# Use typescript to extract types of function parameters in function argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a type setup for a function `myFunction`, but the returned type is not correct.

```js
type Base = {
  [key: string]: (state: any, payload: {
    type: any
    payload?: any
  }) => any
}

const myFunction = <T extends Base>(arg: T) => {

  return {
    actions: {} as {
      [Key in keyof T]: {
        [K in Parameters<T[Key]>[1]['type']]: (arg: Parameters<T[Key]>[1] & { type: K }) => void
      }
    }
  }
}

const reducer1 = (state: boolean, payload: { type: 'foo', payload: number } | { type: 'batman' }) => state
const reducer2 = (state: string, payload: { type: 'bar' }) => state

const {actions} = myFunction({
  domain1: reducer1,
  domain2: reducer2
})
```

The returned `actions` object should have two properties `domain1` and `domain2`, and each domain should have the appropriate functions.

But i cant seem to get the function arguments to be correct:

```js
actions.domain1.batman() // no argument should be required
actions.domain1.foo()    // argument should be number
actions.domain2.bar()    // no argument should be required
```

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-56Sx6s12AB0brgtpDrOA7OoTAMAHoE+SRKZEpSINRBQgABYiVxCcQI6BZACOrkoIIwQZKCDD1oj1AWIYJInjhSTadoGazpDzBaL1PJlOp5Gr+tD4ZooqjCXbMk71FTCW7Y17ufzheLQog5cr3qAA).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLvzZw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, you have helped me so much jcalz:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that `(Parameters<T[Key]>[1] & { type: K })` will have a `type` and a `payload` property, so `(arg: Parameters<T[Key]>[1] & { type: K }) => void` will require an input of that type.  But you really want the input to just be the `payload` property.  That means you just forgot to [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type with `"payload"`:

```
declare const myFunction: <T extends Base>(arg: T) => {
  actions:
  { [Key in keyof T]: { [K in Parameters<T[Key]>[1]['type']]:
    (arg: (Parameters<T[Key]>[1] & { type: K })["payload"]) => void
    // --------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^
  } }
};
```

That gives you the following desirable behavior:

```
actions.domain1.foo(3); // okay
actions.domain1.foo(); // error, requires an argument
```

But you still have the situation where types without `payload` require an argument:

```
actions.domain1.batman() // error, 
// (property) batman: (arg: unknown) => void
actions.domain2.bar() // error
// (property) bar: (arg: unknown) => void
```

It's expecting an argument of type `unknown`, because a type like `{type: "batman"}` doesn't have a known `payload` property, and so literally any type could be at such an index.

---

Instead I think what you'd like is if it's possible for `payload` to be `undefined`, then you'd like `arg` to be an [optional parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters).  We can write a utility type like

```
type FuncWithPossiblyOptionalParam<T> =
  undefined extends T ? (arg?: T) => void : (arg: T) => void;
```

which uses a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to switch between the two types of function.  Then we use it:

```
declare const myFunction: <T extends Base>(arg: T) => {
  actions:
  { [Key in keyof T]: { [K in Parameters<T[Key]>[1]['type']]:
    FuncWithPossiblyOptionalParam<
      (Parameters<T[Key]>[1] & { type: K })["payload"]
    >
  } }
};
```

And now you get the behavior you want:

```
actions.domain1.foo(3); // okay
actions.domain1.foo(); // error, requires an argument
actions.domain1.batman() // okay
actions.domain2.bar() // okay
```

---

That's basically the answer to the question as asked.  Do note though that we can simplify your technique of [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `Parameters<T[Key]>[1]["type"]` and then extracting the corresponding [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) member on the other side.

You can iterate over arbitrary unions in mapped types by using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  So instead of `Parameters<T[Key]>[1]["type"]`, we can iterate over `Parameters<T[Key]>[1]`, and then pull out `type` for the key and `payload` for the value directly:

```
declare const myFunction: <T extends Base>(arg: T) => {
  actions: { [Key in keyof T]:
    { [P in Parameters<T[Key]>[1] as P["type"]]:
      FuncWithPossiblyOptionalParam<P["payload"]>
    };
  };
}
```

That doesn't change anything about the resulting type:

```
actions.domain1.foo(3); // okay
actions.domain1.foo(); // error, requires an argument
actions.domain1.batman() // okay
actions.domain2.bar() // okay
```

But it is simpler.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgC4CeMyAQiFMgLx6FFIDaA1hKQFxJTEBOAS2ABzALo8AFHxDEIPEMFIAaJHFIYA9iAAmPAs2ZkKCpU0PqtugPynS5pAF8AlEjoA+JIvtFH+f0SgkLAIyABiggAeAIyMhjoQ8Bgg-MjwmsB8SGCkYQCuwPDEghk8ADwAKkgQkXLAOlBI1LTukikiPBWuHnGGXkUlmVwORLisANKcSMJIHKSaAGZIFRJ4E9PASAAKKeAQcvxQlSyTpGLuLNFiLADkxhA3YhIjzG38HUiSO-x7B0cVJ0450uYiQADI1vceOMnM4WAAiSzaHTwsTdTwAN00gh0LyIAHp8UgALSksnkimUqnU0meAB6DMZTJejicDkcAG4Asx0pliEhUjo8oh+LEGNJiLJ5EgAEaaTQYCCKVRI3T6EjkaU3Bbym4qkAaZE8YB5MAyiD8JxIAA+kM1PBuMtkYEUN1hbk8MjkDl5WUFwotACY3J8vdK+EJRPrDWq7SYkI6Um6XB7eJLvT6MlkxghilmrQwcvlCnngJIDH0dJoXcJojx-SLosoXlWa8BA-WIEKRYH2c5uURc4MoAA6VsgWsjnWaSQAZmcHKQhKQmjYBocQ6zY+rE+A0Sn8skC6XRIt-E0-FUqQAjnlBKlGoovO9TRBgMQB-1S6Px5OncQXTLVxlzPC9VAcZdJBgc8KH4MhXH-QCpHaHgCjYYBNAAd2AdEkCxHENwGLdf3bEcnX4I8T2qfhz34CCiSgmCLXg2UUmQ95UOAdCsJw1N8NxJg-CYIJoDgRAkAiSJgwIBx7gkgp4AAdUEYgAAstk0KAoEEGUMFIAB5GBS0wb5wEqTw6BeAoEgWYQu2qWo3waZYkGsT52lsZZcP4pB2I+Lo+OxHQuQcBIkhSNIs35IsFNLcoqhqOpnOaCBWhQrzUwrQxNyGF4xkBUgNlmThFmWVZ8phGZTMgP5jlOYErlue5HmePpmGLJSVPUzTtN0gyjMGEzdjAMo8Vear9gtf4Coa0EITGKEkBhFwEVVFExDG9wWTZQxOU-X1+QbC0xVDdNpTlBUlWAaMrD0OMtWnPU1ANW7jVNc1LVZW0FvtBNENdd0ejDTM+QFLsA34YNxTDHgI2EEQbqNe6HXI5NcOBkHsy-YcC2yXJYsGcsWx3WtO27Y7mzakiOzB8nIb7fxCO-bc233ac52PZdV3XbKiMyFndzZw9OdPGiwLB2972gLxNnaV93yZ4cBb-Z1FEorm1x8Zgcp-EnSPI9WiW5rW-ECPYQnEyTZ16Ig5I65S1I0rSdL0wzjIwarzLcKz6ggWzgHsxKnMaKo3LeERPICnofL8zpvKCkL4kSZJUiQA68Y6uKkEqByksaFK0o4jKeiy7W+agdUCqKuZSpWYY2tGVgtiKibaoBeqLiuLxGi2BF7lRVqG6Ie2uqd3rXYGjIhp+Ebe8RF7kVRLah72trV+YITMcO8HGxDCUpR4C7FWVZ6Yzun7421XVEdjE0zQtK1vo1S--uANHU2Bwx06OyG95htNIwI1Pq9ZGf0kyA09GdfaUU1g61xjFEshNS5EBInWWmEMmzEzbDTH+vZdr9kVsRPWQsZzzkXBrHmZdmaoIPDOEW1FaJXggJLB8MtnwiHlh+Xm1DiFkVVkBKixtCH82pnwiiwEjaa0Ev4IAA)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great, but I have encountered an issue if all payloads are mandetory.

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBSgbQNYQgBcUCwATgJYB2A5gLokAUZcwEJc1IANFGHBAAbAPZwAJiUzZsoSJ25YZA4WPEB+BSCUBfAJRRkAPihdtOjBgDGI6mSgBbEADEArtSvBKtw1AA8ACpQEAAe7NTiCLCIEEZMcOS0JAEGxuiW2OQQwK7k1Okypp7edlI6plHShbgA0oRQNFAEICIAZlABjAXV2DgACg35fQlwDtkQ5AiBOHUg9EY4AIz0iFB9OABEchAb9F3u4hCtNBDiwWEQEVHrGyqiErtQ6lBMYJprm3dqu6kmAG4iShnZhgEg3L4Pei-KAAoFKQoWBG6DAWay2exZcSuKwTRa+FjANgcKAAIxEIiEEC4fAhknQUG2JAA5K1yUyaYJ7nTqK4HCSJlB9IYTKx2Gi7MAoJjsRMAEz40XEshUOgc1QSKQM8DEpkkhJMwXQxWWGwS+lwYrowW+JxuDxeWxMKriEQOOA0RYkaU48iLPgAen9-gAtKHTK12OQGlKIA4RH9TvTGVBdWw3dQDeVWuRXTGsT6-QyABaUKITHNR6giADupjAkASCCULrdNFlXtOMvIspReksFoddgAdC33dRFkO9cB00wDIGoFXTIleZdJQgiyJXEIzvyYwBHVyUTEYAclBAj11jieskSzwrzhK0FfUNcbrc76A8vkTE+W4ejttJwSO8ZHnRdH2fV9N23UloCyA8j1OIA).

I am currently looking for a solution.

---

UPDATE: Seems like removing the `?` from the `Base` type solves it...?

Updated playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBSgbQNYQgBcUCwATgJYB2A5gLokAUZcwEJc1IANFGHBAAbAPZwAJiUzZsoSJ25YZA4WMlQuIKAHptUADwBaY1HIQAtiIBuEcVGAALaAEcArhDKUR1c3HJ4NajtHNlIICwR7EVIRIRsoSmAAOhSAfiUAXwBKKGQAPkCQDAyMDABjbzIocxAAMVdqMuAvalyDABUoCAAPdiDI+CQ8pj9aEnac-PRS7DNgV3JW6Rk4JpaEKQyNSOWZXABpQgTWghARADModsZpvb2cAAVjqAe-OHMIdnIEfXacQ5A9DyOAAjPREC8cAAiOQQKH0G4NcQQc40WxdXoQfqQqEqUQSeFQVJQJhgVIkB7QvFqeGTApWESUOzMMAUqmCfHiWm5emM8RKPYlQWZYqlCrUKpmcSuMoQcggtosYBsDhQABGIliEC4fGpEik9nAqoA5OdNcbdRy1CRqK5zGq5VBsjzSMr2OVKsBTLYZXKAEyK1jsEhkKh0S2qfXoQ3yKDGtV+Y1OumulViz3R1bNSpOto1eqNbPUJjLcQiXw0EEkKW++V8XQGYyGDTnL4Jb2WGx2NAxk0J4C+ahJrbncjl73S2V1+wOSiROVj8hQagiADuGjAkD8CCUZYr1D91Z9U79xSypSz6ySe7glaSZpETGNxpyMgboztWK9CAcIlcQjsB1lztB1yAwS9KmvctbwPJIE3IJhX2wBsVw0chaE-ahv1-f9AOgMw3EoKUgA).